# Automatically Updating the UI

Tags: android, user-interface, broadcastreceiver, contentobserver

I have created a quite nice implementation of a Broadcast/BroadcastReceiver where I am pulling down information via a Service from a Web API, Broadcasting the result of the received data and then changing the UI when the OnReceive function is called in the Activity which updates the UI.

The way I am updating the UI though is by passing the 'id' of the row to the database and then pulling the data out again.

This doesn't seem very optimal as I have to access the database twice. Once to save and once to retrieve. How can I optimise this? How can I optimise the process of updating the UI without having to go to the database again?

Options which I have researched:

- Send a Parceable/Serializable object in the Intent when Broadcasting
- Saving the retrieved data in a static class and using that data when onReceive is called.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use a contentobserver on the cursor you open on the database. that way, you only need to react when you receive the notification that something was inserted in the database. That makes a good separation of data and view.

Comment: @njzk2 Is the ContentObserver only achieved through ContentProviders?

Comment: i am not sure, I think it also works without them too, as long as you use the same Uri for registering the notification and for publishing them

Comment: @njzk2 Do you know of any good tutorials?

Comment: this should be trivial enough. choose an Uri for your data (as if you were going to use it for a ContentProvider), then use `context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);` when you modify a data, then use either `FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY` (discouraged) or `FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER` when you create the adapter and override the `onContentChanged` of the adapter to update the cursor yourself. Finally, call `setNotificationUri` on the cursor when you create it so it reacts to modifications.

Comment: I think i'd need a tutorial just to get me going. Though your explanation made some sense, I just need a slightly wider context as I'm still new to Android. Thank you btw for your very kind help.

Comment: I have written an article about saving stuff to database in a simple way: http://njzk2.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/storage-is-simple-part-1-sql/ It uses a contentprovider, but it is not mandatory to use it to retrieve data. The `notifyChange` and `setNotificationUri` are included, you only need to handle the `onContentChanged` in the adapter. (sorry I don't know any tutorial specifically about this point. I may write one at some point, though)